# Tkinter Checkbutton wont keep its check mark post color change

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

So I have a black and white GUI and I need to use check boxes, well I set it up and the check box looks ok until I click it and then suddenly the check mark wont stay past my click. The issue comes from the line that starts changing the color of the button. But I need this color scheme, I also need to be able to see the checkmark though.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

checkCmd= IntVar()
checkCmd.set(False)

test = Checkbutton(master, variable=checkCmd, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, text="Old Testament", \
            bg='black', fg='white', activebackground='black', activeforeground='white')
test.pack()
buttonCmd = Button(master, text="Run Checked Items").pack()


mainloop()
```

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/lawsie/guizero/issues/174) on it on github

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The check icon shares the foreground color which is white, and your activeforeground is also white.

A simple way is to change the `selectcolor` which adjusts the background of the selector:

```
test = Checkbutton(master, variable=checkCmd, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, text="Old Testament",
            bg='black', fg='white', activebackground='black', activeforeground='white',selectcolor="black")
```

Comment: Thank you I couldn't find that, I appreciate your help!