# tkinter Radiobutton doesn't show selection if text foreground value is other than black

Tags: tkinter

if Radio Button Text fg is set any color other than black, it doesn't show the selection but button works. User won't know if radio button is selected or not.

In below code, only Radioactivity selection is shown when click because text fg ='black' and for other 2 button you won't see the selection after clicking on it.

Any thoughts?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()    
window.configure(background ='green')

def selVal():
    print("Selected Radio Button",(selection.get()))
    
   
# radioselect variable  
selection = tk.StringVar()
selection.set("lifetime")

# radioselect buttons 
lifetimeBtn = tk.Radiobutton(window, variable = selection, value = "lifetime", text = "Lifetime",fg='white',bg='green',command =selVal)
elecNoiseBtn = tk.Radiobutton(window, variable = selection, value = "electronic", text = "Electronic Noise",fg='white',bg='green',command =selVal)
radioactivityBtn = tk.Radiobutton(window, variable = selection, value = "radioactive", text = "Radioactivity",fg='black',bg='green',command =selVal)
lifetimeBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
elecNoiseBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
radioactivityBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @TheLizzard Windows10

Comment: Shows the same on Linux though, too;  so it's not just a Windows thing...

Comment: Think you have to use *alt* or *clam* `ttk.Style()`, then set `fieldbackground` --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034896/set-style-for-ttk-combobox

Comment: It is because the *dot* shares the same *foreground* color option of the text, so it is *white* on *white* when it is selected.

Comment: Configure `selectcolor` to other color so you can see it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311242/tkinter-checkbutton-wont-keep-its-check-mark-post-color-change/55312305#55312305) for a sample.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with white color. Any color other than white will work well and show the selection of radiobutton. Now with white color the button works same as the other color but the white mixes with the background white color so we can't see any difference in it. So you can use any color other than white.